# From Kotlin call Java method requiring Function parameter

Tags: java, kotlin, interop

I am having problems converting this chunk of Java to Kotlin:

```
Publishers.map(chain.proceed(request), response -> {
            if (request.getCookies().contains("SOME_VALUE")) { 
                response.cookie(request.getCookies().get(STATE_COOKIENAME).maxAge(0));
            }
            return response;
        });
```

The second parameter of the `map` method (note `Publishers` is not a collection) takes `Function<T,R>`.
I have tried several solutions, including providing a lambda thus:

```
Publishers.map(chain?.proceed(request), {
        x: MutableHttpResponse<*>!,
        y: MutableHttpResponse<*>! -> print("It worked")
    })
```

but that results in:

> Error:(32, 38) Kotlin: Unexpected token
>
> Error:(33, 38) Kotlin: Unexpected token
>
> Error:(31, 27) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun  map(publisher: Publisher!, mapper: Function!): Publisher!
>   cannot be applied to
>   (Publisher>!>?,(MutableHttpResponse<>, MutableHttpResponse<*>) -> Unit)
>
> Error:(31, 56) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is (MutableHttpResponse<*>, MutableHttpResponse<*>) -> Unit but Function>!, MutableHttpResponse<>?>! was expected

and providing a method:

```
return Publishers.map(chain?.proceed(request), ::processCookie)

private fun processCookie(a: MutableHttpResponse<*>?) {
   print("something something something")
}
```

which results in:

> Error:(31, 27) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun  map(publisher: Publisher!, mapper: Function!): Publisher!
>   cannot be applied to
>   (Publisher>!>?,KFunction1<@ParameterName MutableHttpResponse<>?, Unit>)
>
> Error:(31, 56) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<@ParameterName MutableHttpResponse<>?, Unit> but Function>!, MutableHttpResponse<*>?>! was expected

For context I thought it would be fun to attempt [this tutorial](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-oauth2-okta/guide/index.html) in kotlin.

Comment: The third solution was to leave that code as Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not specify the return type in the lambda, it is inferred by Kotlin. The last example did not work, because the return type of the function is `Unit`, which is `void` in Java. I would try the following:

```
return Publishers.map(chain?.proceed(request), ::processCookie)

private fun processCookie(a: MutableHttpResponse<*>?) : MutableHttpResponse<*>? {
   print("something something something")
   return a
}
```

It may also work if you write

```
return Publishers.map(chain?.proceed(request)) { 
  print("something something something")
  it
}
```

We use here the default parameter name of the Lambda in Kotlin - namely `it`. Kotlin compiler will infer types for you. It is also allowed in Kotlin to move the last lambda parameter of a function outside of brackets.

The last thing for the functional interfaces from Java, e.g. `Function<T,R>`. You may need to use the name explicitly, e.g.

```
return Publishers.map(chain?.proceed(request), Function<T,R> { 
  print("something something something")
  it
})
```

where `T` and `R` has to be substituted with the actual types

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I will give those a go :)

Comment: The third suggestion (also providing the type parameters to the Java `Function` type) has compiled.  Thank you.